# How to Remove Certain Screen Options and Table Columns from post type in wp_list_table?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, wp-list-table, screen-options, screen-columns

On the page where we list all posts made: `example.domain.com/wp-admin/edit.php`

There is a Screen Options tab in the upper right corner. Upon clicking this, a menu slides down. Contained within this slide down menu, are check boxes. When checking or unchecking these check boxes, certain columns in the post table are shown/hidden, depending on whether they are checked or not.

I am looking for a way to programmatically obtain a list of all of these registered Screen Options for this post type (Default post type: post). Once I obtain a list of these registered screen options, I will check to see if a certain array of options are listed. If they match a listed item, I plan on removing those options.

[image: WordPress - Screen Options - List Posts]
[Click Here For Full Size Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xy1f.png)

**Question**
How can I programmatically obtain a list of all registered Screen Options on post types (page with table listing each post)?

Looking for a solution similar to the solution provided for [removing certain screen options and meta boxes from add/edit post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/56628/9579).

Comment: This is a per user option and saved into the user meta via ajax. Maybe you want to alter your question based on this information.

Comment: Hey @Michael Ecklund, did my answer not address your question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need is to modify the `$columns` variable that is used during list display which you can modify using the `'manage_posts_columns'` and `'manage_pages_columns'` hooks for `post_type='post'` and `post_type='page'`, respectively. If you want to ignore custom post types you can inspect the 2nd parameter passed to `'manage_posts_columns'` as I did in my example to show how.

So let's assume you want to get rid of the *"Comments"* screen option and it's associated column which you see in these screenshot for Posts and Pages, respectively:

[image]
[image]

Drop the following class into your theme's `functions.php` file or in a plugin you might be building and this code will remove the *"Comments"* screen option and it's associated column *(Since this answer is similar to your [other question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56606/how-can-i-remove-certain-screen-options-and-meta-boxes/56628), I added a `"2"` to the class name, hence in `Michael_Ecklunds_Admin_Customizer2`):*

```
class Michael_Ecklunds_Admin_Customizer2 {
  function __construct() {
    add_action( 'manage_pages_columns', array( $this, 'manage_columns' ) );
    add_action( 'manage_posts_columns', array( $this, 'manage_columns' ), 10, 2 );
  }
  function manage_columns( $columns, $post_type = 'page' ) { //2nd param not passed for pages
    if ( in_array( $post_type, array( 'post', 'page' ) ) ) {
      // This is only for posts and pages, 'if (in_array(...))' just illustrates how.
      unset( $columns['comments'] );
    }
    return $columns;
  }
}
new Michael_Ecklunds_Admin_Customizer2();
```

And here's what it looks like after you've added the above code to a WordPress 3.4 site:

[image]
[image]

Using the [**Zend debugger within PhpStorm**](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/tag/zend-debugger/) here is the inspection of `$columns` within the `'manage_posts_columns'` hook so you can see what values a default installation of WordPress 3.4 has for the Post edit list *(I've circled the array indexes I referenced in my example, i.e. `$columns['comments']`:*

[image]

Hopefully this is what you were looking for?

Comment: Awww, you’re back! :)

Comment: @toscho Thanks for noticing. I've been less than healthy and clients have been demanding, so back only a bit.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel How would I go about removing let's say, "wpseo-score" from the post type of let's say, "business"?

Comment: @MichaelEcklund What is `'wpseo-score'`?; are you using a plugin or theme that adds it, like maybe WordPress SEO by Yoast? Do any of these links help? https://gist.github.com/2927217 https://gist.github.com/2997070 http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-wordpress-seo-by-yoast-columns-filters-additions-to-admin-bar-need-to-remove

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Wow thanks. all I simply had to do was `add_filter('wpseo_use_page_analysis', '__return_false');` ... and all of those cluttered columns are gone now. But let's say a plugin wasn't so graceful in providing hooks for it's users? Could you please update you answer geared for removing a custom column name from a custom post type? I can assure you I am not the only one in this community that could benefit from it. Aside from that, thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: @MichaelEcklund As far as I know, I've already explained how to remove a custom column name from a custom post type; look in the `$columns` variable to see what element to `unset()`. Realize that I can't know in advance what someone might name the array index so it's going to require inspection such as with a `var_dump($columns); exit;` Or maybe I don't follow your question?

Comment: P.S. @MichaelEcklund Also, have you considered maybe getting PhpStorm + Zend Debugger? With it, all this knowledge would be at your fingertips too. :)

Comment: For future readers: If anyone don't see their column names listed within the `$columns` array, increase up the priority. Also `manage_post_columns` is filter hook so better to use `add_filter` (`add_action` works fine too). And for custom post type you can also use the filter `manage_${post_type}_posts_columns` filter to avoid adding conditional logic