# Create a Page template selector page

Tags: customization, themes, templates, core

I'm running around with an idea in my head that I would like to make but I don't really know how or where to start.

In a custom theme I had to make serveral templates for one of my clients. 
I noticed that I had around 20 possible templates for my client (because he wanted to have "multiple" options)

You can imagine that the dropdown list for the templates was immense.
So I was wondering how I can replace the default dropdown with a new screen or a pop-up to create a visual reference to the possible templates.

It would be even cooler if there are thumbnails of templates generated based on how the template looks. (like Google used to do a while ago)
But this is part two. First I would like to know how to even replace the dropdown.

Any thoughts/ideas?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718782/how-to-override-a-wordpress-core-function) but.... well I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could develop your own metabox for the page (with custom styling, probably) that allows selection of the template.  I don't know that generating screenshots is feasible, but you could definitely have it pull from some sort of associated file (eg: template name is template-name.php, screenshot is template-name.png).

With the replacement selection method generated, you can then just use [`remove_meta_box()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) to remove the default input box (see: [Get List of Registered Meta Boxes and Removing Them](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56104/get-list-of-registered-meta-boxes-and-removing-them)) and you should be set!

Comment: That's a great idea. Thnx. I didn't know a `remove_meta_box()` existed. Now I can custom save the `template_name` to the database and call it upon pageload or something. Thnx

Comment: If this solved the problem, please mark it as the solution so that it doesn't show up in unanswered questions.

Comment: This didn't solve my problem this is merely a solution to a problem. I would like to leave the question open for a little longer to see if there is anyone else who has a different idea. If I do work with your solution I will mark this answer as solved!

Comment: Indeed I created a metabox that holds the templates and was able to update the `_wp_page_template` with another template. Used `remove_meta_box()` to hide the attributes. Thnx @m0r7if3r