# global $wp_meta_boxes returns NULL

Tags: dashboard, globals

When I call `global $wp_meta_boxes;` it returns null.
I'm trying to calling like:

```
class my_class()
{
   public function __construct(){
     add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup' , array( $this , 'my_meta_boxes' ));
   }
   public function my_meta_boxes(){
      global $wp_meta_boxes;
      return $wp_meta_boxes;
   }
}
```

The class is working fine, but I cannot make it work.

**[EDIT]**

To make understand better the issue, my objective is the one actually answered in this question:

- [Get List of Registered Meta Boxes and Removing Them](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56104/get-list-of-registered-meta-boxes-and-removing-them).

I need to retrieve `metaboxes` for specific admin pages. The problem is that the `global`is not working for me.

I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Hmm, and what exactly do you mean by "cannot make it work"? What are you expecting to do exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to get the default WP metaboxes like "At a Glance" etc. Any Ideas? `$wp_meta_boxes` should have those right?

Comment: It depends on the context in which you are calling it. If the default metaboxes aren't registered, then you can't access them. Generally speaking, you should never touch these global variables directly.

Comment: Thanks @fuxia, I know that I shouldn't but my question is then how to get those in the WP dashboard? Is there another way? I couldn't find other solutions.

Comment: `$wp_meta_boxes` contains the dashboard widgets when I inspect it on the `wp_dashboard_setup` hook. Your code isn't testable as-is, so I can't say what you're doing differently.

Comment: @Milo ok thanks. How do you inspect it? That's helpful likewise.

Comment: @Milo ok so I created a function to debug the global and it gets data only when visiting the home dashboard. I thought it was a global storing values when initialising WP.